# AWS Lambda + Firestore database: add() not inserting document data in collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to use Firestore on AWS Lambda in Nodejs. Here is the initialization part of the database connection:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.cred);
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),     
});
var db = admin.firestore();
```

But whenever I try the insertion operation, It does not insert the data in a 'test' collection.

Insertion code:

```
async (events, context) => {
    try {            
              var firestoreResult = await db.collection('packagescan12').add({
                                    packageId: scan.packageId,                                  
                                    status: "unsynced",
                                    timestamp: new Date()
               });                            
               console.log('Added document with ID: ', firestoreResult.id);
    } catch(err) {                    
               console.log("Error in inserting: ", err);
    };
}
```

In the logs, it says `'Added document with ID: undefined'`

**EDIT**

As highlighted from the answer given by Frank van Puffelen, `databaseURL` is not required for initialising application.

Logs from CloudWatch when inserting two documents in a loop:

```
Error in inserting:  Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181)
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:124:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:426:23)
    at DocumentReference.create (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:285:14)
    at CollectionReference.add (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2021:28)
    at /var/task/index.js:170:80
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async AsyncIterableX.[Symbol.asyncIterator] (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/ix/asynciterable/operators/map.js:18:28)
    at async Object.toArray (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/ix/asynciterable/toarray.js:18:22) {
  code: 4,
  details: 'Deadline exceeded',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

Comment: Please share your code for insertion. Note that `databaseURL: "https://database_id_here.firebaseio.com"`is the URL corresponding to the Realtime Database, not Firestore.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have made the edits and also noted the information about the databaseURL. I have also added some information about the same in the edit.

Comment: Dont you see the new doc in the Firestore console??

Comment: No I don't, as I mentioned earlier, it says added with id: undefined

Comment: From the code you shared it should be saved in the DB. Again, note that there are two different Database services in Firebase. Take care not mixing up the RTDB and Firestore when looking at the console. **You should share the entire code in order for us to further help you**.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I understand your query regarding sharing more code, but since it's my employers code, I can only share similar code instead of the actual one. Hope you understand. Lastly, can it be because of the insertion code not "awaiting" the execution?

Comment: "Can it be because of the insertion code not "awaiting" the execution?" => This is exactly one reason why I asked for the entire code, to see how you call this async function. I do understand you cannot share the proprietary code, but I'm afraid the community will have difficulties helping you without more info.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I get your point. Will get back to you on this, and thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

> I then tried opening the databaseURL: "https://database_id_here.firebaseio.com" in the browser and it says "not found" as a response in the browser.

This is the expected behavior. Firebase has two databases: Cloud Firestore, and Realtime Database. Your code is using the Firestore API, while the URL is for the Realtime Database, which apparently was never created for this project.

Since you're only trying to use Firestore in your code the fact that Realtime Database was not created is not a problem. In fact, I'd recommend removing that URL from the code, as it's not needed and since it confused you, it may confuse others.

To see your Firestore database, go to htts://firebase.google.com/console, select the project, and then select Firestore in the left navigation.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense now. I thought that `databaseURL` might be wrong and it was causing the database connection to be set up incorrectly, hence not inserting the data in the collection. Since, it's not required anymore, I have edited the question. Is the add() not "awaiting"  for insertion and just ignoring the operation? I have posted the logs of the error occurring as well.